# IntelliJ IDEA How to hide git author in code

Tags: java, git, kotlin, intellij-idea

I think a recent update of JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA added a new git feature to show who most recently authored a section of code.  This is a nice feature but I don't want to see it all the time.  How do I hide it?

[image: IntelliJ git author example]

The feature is between lines 596 and 597, indicating that this is new code.  It will show the name of the person who most recently changed the code if the code is not new.